# Is there a supported way to change the filter and view in a subgrid automatically based on the value on the form in new UI

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-uci

Is there a supported way to change the filter and view in a subgrid automoatically based on the value on the form in new UI.

Comment: need more details, what field? any relationship between them? did you try anything? Anyway needed custom script to achieve what you want on my first guess

Comment: a custom field. yes there is relation ship between the field and the form. details on the sub grid and the field.i am trying to achieve changing the view and the filter on the subgrid.filter should be based on the custom field on the form